# Display the json data in angularjs using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

my json object contains the list of Questions followed by the options.How can we display the Question followed by options.Here is my code please check it once.

Comment: here is my code check it once.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XNi7I9V2US21NnpP1Mmu?p=preview

Comment: default,we need to display the question.when click on question display the respective option of that question.how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <div id="Content1">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "q in questions">
           <td>{{q.question}}</td>
           <td ng-repeat="answer in q.answers">{{answer.answers}} {{answer.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: default,we need to display the question.when click on question display the respective option of that question.how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in QuestionsList" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000000;">
    <div>{{question.Question}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="options in question.options">{{options.option}}</div>
<div>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hfrbalq7dmwzZMDoHzNv?p=preview

I changed the HTML a little bit so it's better readable when rendered.

**EDIT based on your comment:**

You can simply toggle the class to show/hide. I added a directive and a css file to your code.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/PixQYfE1psUx9OEvSsJQ?p=preview

Comment: default,we need to display the question.when click on question display the respective option of that question.how can i do?

Comment: my directive is defined like.


angular.module('PoliticalOrg.admin').controller('CreatePoolController',function( $scope,MessageService,CountryService ) {
});

when i add the directive('toggleClass', function() { }); function getting error.how can solve this?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr to this problem? I am not sure how you are trying to implement the directive so I can't really help you unfortunately. Are you applying it to your scripts.js the way I did in the plnkr or are you trying to make it an external file or something?

Comment: one more thing,ng-if not working in angular.min.js 1.0.7 version,when i changed the version 1.4.x version ng-if working but getting module exception in console.how can i solve this ?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=PoliticalOrg&p1=Err…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

Comment: Why don't you follow the url https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=PoliticalOrg&p1=Err and see if it's any help to you?

Comment: Also I can't know about all your errors and what your code might be like. I answered your original question with a proper solution. If you have trouble with something else please make another question in SO about it and probably someone can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this http://plnkr.co/edit/VXrWEgJ77y8NzRU8pQ63?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-strict-di>

  <head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <style>ul { padding-left: 0; } li { list-style: none; }</style>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.13" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="'+ document.location.pathname +'" />')
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="main-content" ng-controller="QuestionCtrl">
      <div id="Content1">
        <div class='question' ng-repeat="question in questions">
          <h2>{{question.question}}</h2>
          <div class='answers' ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
            <h4>answer {{$index + 1}}</h4>
            <p>{{answer.value}}</p>
            <p>{{answer.answers}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this, if you this is right let me know.

```
    {{quest.Question}}

    <span ng-repeat = "option in quest.options">
    strong text<br/>
      {{option.option}}
    </span>
    <br/>
```

Comment: ok.default,we need to display the question.when click on question display the respective option of that question.how can i do?

Comment: <body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="main-content" ng-controller="QuestionCtrl">
      <div id="Content1">
        <div class='question' ng-repeat="question in questions">
          <a ng-init="status=false;" ng-click="status=true">
            <h2>{{question.question}}</h2>
          </a>
          <div ng-show="status" class='answers' ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
            <h4>answer {{$index + 1}}</h4>
            <p>{{answer.value}}</p>
            <p>{{answer.answers}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, initialize a variable `show` to false using `ng-init`. Then set it to `true` on element click using `ng-click`. Use ng-show to hide options initially. Once `show` is true, options will be visible

```
<div id="Content1">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "q in questions">
       <td ng-init="show=false;" ng-click="show=true">{{q.question}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="answer in q.answers" ng-show="show">{{answer.answers}} {{answer.value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNi7I9V2US21NnpP1Mmu?p=preview). It works as per your requirement. Clicking a question will show you the respective answers.

```
<div ng-repeat="quest in QuestionsList" ng-click='clik($index)'>{{quest.Question}}
    <div ng-show='show === $index'>
      <div ng-repeat="quess in quest.options">{{quess.option}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```